# how to select drop down option and should click on the following values within drop down list in selenium webdriver java code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

here is code html code. here using java selenium code i need to click on logout option to close the session. when clicked on drop down button, logout option will appear and i need to click on that link

```
<div class="sp-info">
abc
<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
</a> 
<ul class="main-menu" style="display: block;">
<li>
<a href="profile.php">
</li> 
<li>
<a href="change_password.php">
</li>
<li>
<a href="logout.php">
```

here is java selenium code.

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "owner/login.php");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='admin_user_name']")).sendKeys("qwerty");
            driver.findElement(By.name("admin_password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='admin_password']")).sendKeys("12345678");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'sp-info')]"));
            Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
            mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
            WebElement wb1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'logout.php')]"));
            mouse.moveToElement(wb1).click();
```

Comment: how you try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath for getting the path for the element. 
you can get the XPath using browser.
For Example:
       element = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@test-id='logout.php']");

Comment: thank you. but problem is logout option is within the dropdown option  and showing error message as "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" and i used the following code WebElement mySelectElm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'logout.php')]"));

Answer (score 0):

You can try using actions to click on element in the drop dow.

```
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wb = driver.findElement(<xpath_to_go_to_menu_dropdown>);
    Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);
    mouse.moveToElement(wb).click();
    WebElement wb1 = driver.findElement(<xpath_to_go_value_in_dropdown>);
    mouse.moveToElement(wb1).click();
    mouse.build();
    mouse.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it seems you're being told the element is not visible.

Have you tried using explicit wait? So that when you open the menu that contains the Logout option you give it a chance to appear, e.g.:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'logout.php')]")));
```

Hopefully then it should find it, and you'll be ok to interact with it.